# How to embed an HTML/script snippet into a react.js page without jQuery?

Tags: reactjs, embed

I created a react website using create-react-app. In one of the pages, I want to embed an airbnb preview, see below code and screenshot provided by airbnb.

How can I insert this code into my React components? (NB I don't want to use jQuery)

```
<div
  class="airbnb-embed-frame"
  data-id="21917882"
  data-view="home"
  data-hide-price="true"
  style="width:450px;height:300px;margin:auto"
>
  <a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/21917882?s=51">
    <span>View On Airbnb</span>
  </a>
  <a 
    href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/21917882?s=51" 
    rel="nofollow"
    >T2 hypercentre Capitole/St-Sernin, quiet &amp; bright
  </a>
  <script async="" src="https://www.airbnb.com/embeddable/airbnb_jssdk" />
</div>;
```

[The component created by this code, which I want to embed in the react page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mTaZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does go quite against React principles, but you could load the embed script with something like [`react-async-script-loader`](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader) (or a custom solution) and then call the provided `AirbnbAPI.bootstrap()` function on render or when the component mounts.

**[Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7j0pvnprnj)**

```babel
import React, { Component } from "react";
import scriptLoader from "react-async-script-loader";

const Preview = ({ isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed }) => {
  if (isScriptLoaded && isScriptLoadSucceed) {
    window.AirbnbAPI.bootstrap();
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="airbnb-embed-frame"
      data-id="21917882"
      data-view="home"
      data-hide-price="true"
      style={{ width: 450, height: 300, margin: "auto" }}
    >
      <a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/21917882?s=51">
        <span>View On Airbnb</span>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/21917882?s=51" rel="nofollow">
        T2 hypercentre Capitole/St-Sernin, quiet &amp; bright
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default scriptLoader(["https://www.airbnb.com/embeddable/airbnb_jssdk"])(
  Preview
);
```

Comment: thanks! But this doesn't build the complete component: we only get the pictures, not the text and labels below. (see screenshot of the expected result, in my original message). Any idea how to get the whole thing?

Comment: @xiaoju Change the height of the div?

Comment: indeed changing height to 500 solved my issue, thank you!
BTW, what is it in react-async-script-loader that goes against React principles? What would be the React way? [Code splitting](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#code-splitting)?

Comment: @xiaoju It’s more that the airbnb script is directly manipulating the DOM. React basically doesn’t know what’s going on in that component.